# How do you reset the PlayStation 2 Slim when it's powered on?

Tags: ps2

I used to love playing on my own PS2 Slim, but it's been many years now since I've owned one and in that time, I've forgotten how to reset the console whilst it's powered on. Just to clarify - by reset, I recall that there was a way to make the console reboot so that the current game session would be lost, and the PlayStation would essentially reboot itself. Would anybody be able to clarify?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on a regular PS2, not sure about the slim, so ignore this question and/or ask me to delete it if its wrong.

Holding the power button down turns it off entirely.

Simply tapping the power button resets the console. (Your answer)

Comment: @jebus-irl - Thank you, this rings a bell. I'll accept, but if anyone knows otherwise please let us know.